# combining dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe:

```
>>> g.head(15)
Out[13]: 
         Date      S     E          code  Last
0  2017-11-02   22500 2017-11-10       P 195.00
1  2017-11-02   22500 2017-11-10       C 175.00
2  2017-11-02   22375 2017-11-10       P 135.00
3  2017-11-02   22375 2017-11-10       C 245.00
4  2017-11-02   22625 2017-11-10       P 230.00
5  2017-11-02   22625 2017-11-10       C 125.00
6  2017-11-06   22500 2017-11-10       P 100.00
7  2017-11-06   22500 2017-11-10       C 180.00
8  2017-11-06   22375 2017-11-10       P  60.00
9  2017-11-06   22375 2017-11-10       C 270.00
10 2017-11-06   22625 2017-11-10       P 170.00
11 2017-11-06   22625 2017-11-10       C 120.00
12 2017-11-07   22500 2017-11-10       P  20.00
13 2017-11-07   22500 2017-11-10       C 495.00
14 2017-11-07   22375 2017-11-10       P  13.00
```

The above dataframe has values on every date. I have another dataframe which has a subset of dates from the above DF, but an additional column called Q.

```
>>> g1
Out[18]: 
        Date    S     E            code  Last        Q
0 2017-11-10   22500 2017-11-17       P 170.00     828.47
1 2017-11-10   22625 2017-11-17       P 180.00     646.91
2 2017-11-10   22750 2017-11-17       C 145.00     651.84
3 2017-11-17   22250 2017-11-24       P 165.00     707.57
4 2017-11-17   22375 2017-11-24       P 195.00     607.16
5 2017-11-17   22500 2017-11-24       C 175.00     666.56
6 2017-11-24   22375 2017-12-01       P 140.00     834.13
7 2017-11-24   22500 2017-12-01       P 185.00     763.76
8 2017-11-24   22625 2017-12-01       C 165.00     750.45
```

Note that g has 6 entries for each date- 3 different S values and 2 different code values for each S, while g1 has only 3 (only one code for each S).

Now I want to select data from both these dataframes the following way:

1. start date = each individual date in g1
2. end date = date prior to next start date
3. for all dates between a start and end date, select the data from g but only for the combination of S value and code that is selected in g1.
4. to this selected data, append values for Q which are constant for each S/code combination from start to end date.

I decided to do the merging/appending part first:

```
h = g.set_index(['Date','S','E','code'])
h1 = g1.set_index(['Date','S','E','code'])
f = h.merge(pd.DataFrame(h1['Q']), how= 'left',left_index= True, right_index= True )
f_final = f.reset_index()
```

Now I need to:

1. remove the S/E/code combinations not is g1 from this df
2. forward fill value for Q to fill nans based on S/E/code combination

what's the best way to go about this? Should I avoid appending as the first step ass I am doing here?